# Elasticsearch how to extend analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch

There are analyzers given such as `standard analyzer`

Suppose you want to modify tokenizer of standard analyzer, can you do something like

```
"my_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
  "char_filter": "standard_char_filter",
  "filter": "standard_filter"
}
```

i.e, base your analyzer on an existing analyzer and customize it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [redefine the `standard analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition_5) you need to define a custom one, like this:

```
PUT /standard_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",    <-- change this
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"       
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, since the `standard` analyzer uses the `standard` tokenizer, if you change the tokenizer to something else, it would not be a `standard` analyzer anymore, it would be your custom one with a `lowercase` token filter. However, it's perfectly ok for you to create your custom analyzer based on the `standard` one.